# SharePoint 2013 - How to preview images in Style Library folders

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint 2013, inside my Style Library, I have a folder with 100 images.  What must I do to display a preview of each image within this Style Library image directory, for each image that is in it, rather than just displaying links that open the image in a seperate tab?

So far, I made an attempt of creating a new standard  view and added the image content type to the new view, but it doesn't display a preview of each image.

What must I do?

Answer (score 1):

Assign a display template with below code to the view. I am displaying the preview in the 'Title' column. You can create a different column and update the code as needed. The 'Name' column has to be part of the view for this to work.

```
(function () {
    var titleFieldCtx = {};
    titleFieldCtx.Templates = {};
    titleFieldCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        "Title": { //
            "View": TitleFieldViewTemplate
        }
    };

    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(
        titleFieldCtx
    );

})();

function TitleFieldViewTemplate(ctx) {
    var item = ctx.CurrentItem;
    var validFileTypes = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']; //Valid image file types
    if (validFileTypes.indexOf(item.File_x0020_Type) >= 0 && item.FileRef) {
        return "<img src='" + item.FileRef + "'"; //build the image html. Set the height and width as needed
    }
    else {
        return item.Title;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Change the property of the image and set the content type as `Image`
2. Edit view and choose field `Preview`
3. Save the view

This will add a new field to the view which basically gives a preview of the image

Comment: Doing this adds a column for 'Preview' but the where the preview image should be there is only a generic white icon. Any tips?

Edit: Same result with 'Thumbnail Preview'.

Answer (score 0):

My quick and dirty approach is to open that library in Windows Explorer view, then changing the view to Thumbnails... and voila, you can preview all images.